# Can i encapsulate the creation of similar threads into a method?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, refactoring, runnable

I'm writing a search function that is doing multiple API calls that i would like to execute asynchronous and collect their results. All my threads with their runnables look similar which made we wonder if i could encapsulate the those threads into a method since only 2 lines change per thread.

It looks similar to this:

```
List<BookResponse> allMatches = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();

Thread searchBookName = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        String someParam = someMethod();
        List<BookResponse> matches = fetchMethod(someParam);
        synchronized (allMatches) {
            allMatches.addAll(matches);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CustomException(e);
    }
});
threads.add(searchBookName);
searchBookName.start();

Thread searchBookContent = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        int intParam = anyMethod();
        List<BookResponse> matches = differentFetchMethod(intParam);
        synchronized (allMatches) {
            allMatches.addAll(matches);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CustomException(e);
    }
});
threads.add(searchBookContent);
searchBookContent.start();

/*
*
*
* More Threads...
*
*
*/

for (Thread search : searches) {
    search.join();
}

return new ResponseEntity<List<BookResponse>>(allMatches, HttpStatus.OK);
```

These thread blocks take up a lot of space in the code and are very repetetive, they are made in this pattern with only the 2 commented lines changing:

```
Thread searchSomething = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        //Always 1 method call for a param, params are different types
        //Always 1 api call giving back results
        synchronized (allMatches) {
            allMatches.addAll(matches);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CustomException(e);
    }
});
threads.add(searchSomething);
searchSomething.start();
```

I tried to come up with an interface to solve this, but i end up having to implements those 2 lines of code anyways somehow, so i that didn't make the code any cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't making or sub-classing Threads you should be making Runnables (also look at Future, Callable, Exectutor and thread pools).

```
abstract class AbstractBookSearcher<ParamType> implements Runnable {
    private final ParamType searchParam;
    AbstractBookSearcher(ParamType searchParam) {
        this.searchParam = searchParam;
    }
    public void run() throws Exception {
        try {
            List<BookResponse> matches = search(searchParam);
            synchronized (allMatches) {
                allMatches.addAll(matches);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CustomException(e);
        }
    }
    protected abstract List<BookResponse> search(ParamType searchParam);
}
```

Then sub-class that:

```
class BookNameSearcher extends AbstractBookSearcher<String> {
    protected abstract List<BookResponse> search(String searchParam) {
        return fetchMethod(searchParam);
    }
}
```

or:

```
class BookContentSearcher extends AbstractBookSearcher<Integer> {
    protected abstract List<BookResponse> search(Integer searchParam) {
        return differentFetchMethod(searchParam);
    }
}
```

Then you can start the threads with the custom and type safe runnables, with the search parameters that you want:

```
new Thread(new BookNameSearcher(someMethod()));
new Thread(new BookContentSearcher(anyMethod()));
```

Comment: Oh right that makes a lot of sense, thank you, will be looking into it!

Answer (score 0):

A java 8's lambda function can be put to use to avoid strong binding of no of parameters and its type.

We need to make the `fetchMethod(String someParam)` with varying number of arguments of different types.

```
fetchMethod(int someParam, String someParam2)
```

```
    private void executeAllThreads() {
        List<BookResponse> allMatches = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();

        Supplier<List<BookResponse>> searchBookNameSupplier = ()->fetchMethod(5);
        Thread searchBookName = getThread(searchBookNameSupplier, allMatches);
        threads.add(searchBookName);
        searchBookName.start();

        Supplier<List<BookResponse>> bookResponseSupplier = ()->differentFetchMethod("stringParam");
        Thread searchBookContent = getThread(bookResponseSupplier,allMatches);
        threads.add(searchBookContent);
        searchBookContent.start();

        /*
         *
         *
         * More Threads...
         *
         *
         */

        for (Thread search : searches) {
            search.join();
        }
    }


    private Thread getThread(Supplier<List<BookResponse>> bookResponseSupplier, List<BookResponse> allMatches) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                List<BookResponse> matches = bookResponseSupplier.get();
                synchronized (allMatches) {
                    allMatches.addAll(matches);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new CustomException(e);
            }
        });
        return thread;
    }
```

Few more points to consider for refactoring.

- Avoid creating threads manually use Executors threadpool like `Executors.newCacheThreadPool().submit(searchBookName)`
- If you need the list at the very end after fetching all responses,use callable and addAll() after `join()ing` all threads,to avoid using synchronizedList